# Is it better to compose multiple AJAX calls parallel or serial?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm developing a single-page application, which sends multiple AJAX request to the server.

The system works with polling, because some data-request can take about 10-20minutes to calculate.

- client asks server for data
- server hands out a job-id
- client asks server every few seconds for the result

The polling algorithm lowers the polling frequency over time, stopping at intervals of 10seconds.

But when a client sends different data requests in a short time, he ends up with about 10-20 job-ids and starts polling for all of them.

**Is it better to simply do it this way and let the browser handle those requests in parallel or should I *schedule* every request and *serialize* them all?**

**Would it bring performance benefits to serialize them?**

Comment: Why not have an API that allows the client to poll for **multiple** jobs in a single request?

Comment: Don't worry about doing it serially, but definitely consider Pointy's suggestion.

Comment: the browser handle that itself. Depends on your browser it will only open 2-6 parallel request at once, opening the next when one of this 2-6 requests are done.

Comment: I thought about this, but this would require to rewrite the interface between server and client and I hoped for a faster solution :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each initial request returns a unique id and each page has a unique user id then you can poll on what information for each request.

In the JSON I would return the results for any completed request, and the current status of those that haven't completed, such as whether it has started being processed, and perhaps a percentage of completion, or how many requests are ahead of that request.

This will simplify the work as you won't be making several polling calls, but just one, getting back a complex result to give feedback to the user the status of each request.

I find it useful to give some information on status for long-running queries otherwise the user may think the request was lost.

Answer (score 1):

Some months ago, I faced performance issues due to multiple ajax calls, but I haven't investigated deeper this topic since then : [High latencies loading stores in an ExtJS 4.1 MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14755157/1636522).